# Postfix - Multiple Recipient Source Check

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postfix, ldap

I have successfully setup Postfix on Ubuntu 18.04 using relay_recipient_maps via two different methods but I can only appear to use one method in the config file.

First method is using LDAP queries to our AD servers for every email to check if the address exists. 
LDAP Method:
relay_recipient_maps = ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap_relay_recipients.cf

I have also got a script to generate a file every X minutes of valid email addresses.
File: 
relay_recipient_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relay_recipients

What I would like to do is use LDAP as the primary method and use the file as a secondary check only if LDAP is unsuccessful in finding the address.

Is this possible?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Adding to the question: Even if it checks both each time and only requires 1 of them to return that it is a valid recipient. That would still allow some issues to occur with the live ldap queries as the file will have a fairly up to date list (say within an hour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, issue the *ldap* method first, then the *hash* file :

```
relay_recipient_maps=ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap_relay_recipients.cf, hash:/etc/postfix/relay_recipients
```

Comment: Thanks @Reda Salih. It appears so simple, but couldn't find on anyone doing this. I turned on debug peer list and can see if LDAP doesn't find it, it checks the file. Really appreciate your time.

Comment: Glad to hear that ;)